# does Consistency at ACID, CAP theorem means the same?

Tags: acid

In both **ACID**, **CAP** theorem the "c" stands for "consistency".

Can you explain if the "**consistency**" at both (acid, cap theorem) principles means the 
same?

in case of not - can you explain why?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is C in CAP theorem not same as C in ACID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813282/why-is-c-in-cap-theorem-not-same-as-c-in-acid)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.

Took from the [***Wikipedia*** site:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)

> Consistency as defined in the CAP theorem is quite different from the consistency guaranteed in ACID database transactions.